# add new row every second via php mysql jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to add new row to div.list once a second without **deleting or refreshing** the last row or **refreshing** the page. How would I go about achieving this?

Here is my code so far (just replace content of test2.php to xx to make it work):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.get( 'http://example.com/php/test2.php', function(newRowCount){
      $('#rowcounter').html( newRowCount );
    });
  },1000); //
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="log">

    </div>
    <p>There are <span id='rowcounter'>xx</span> rows in the DB.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code in my page:

```
<div class="list">
   <div>new row1</div>
   <div>new row2</div>
   <div>new row3</div>
   <div>new row4</div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what your issue is since it is very broad. What have you tried and what problems have you encountered? You need a way to track what was previously sent...do you have that?

Comment: I want add new row without delet or refresh last rows. this code only replace new row with last row.

Comment: Well the answer below already gave you the append suggestion. Your last statement is just far too broad...and you need to focus on more specific parts of it when asking. Seems to me you need to study some tutorials and dig through the jQuery API to understand what tools are available to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append to your list what you want without delete last row

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.get( 'http://example.com/php/test2.php', function(newRowCount){
      $('#rowcounter').append( newRowCount );
    });
  },1000); //
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="log">

    </div>
    <p>There are <span id='rowcounter'>xx</span> rows in the DB.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank but the code just append one row...also ...what about content of 'http://example.com/php/test2.php'?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://example.com/php/test2.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: {id : $('#list div').length},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function( data ) {
                    $('#list').append( data );
                    $('#rowcounter').html( $('#list div').length );
                }
            });
        },1000); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="list">

    </div>
    <p>There are <span id="rowcounter">0</span> rows in the DB.</p>

</body>
</html>





<?php 

//Listing: http://example.com/php/test2.php

$id = isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:0;

echo '<div>new row'.$id.'</div>';

?>
```